# SQL datediff function resulted in an overflow

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlexception

I am calculating `TotalHours` of a employee worked in office based on `Intime` and `Outtime` resultant in the form of `hh.mm` like `8.30`.

So, I wrote below sql query :

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, sum(DateDiff(mi,isnull(In_Time,0),isnull(Out_Time,0))/60) +
sum(round(DateDiff(mi,isnull(In_Time,0),isnull(Out_Time,0))%60,2))/100.0    +
sum(round(DateDiff(ss,isnull(In_Time,0),isnull(Out_Time,0)),2))/10000.0 as
TotalHours from HR_EMPLOYEES
```

The above sql server query was running correctly intially, but now it is giving following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of 
dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a 
less precise datepart.
```

Could anybody please help me to get rid off of this?

Comment: Any reason you can't just use `DateDiff` with the hours option instead of all these formulae? I'm also betting that since you are checking for nulls, you are getting minimum date back - and since you are asking for seconds that's what's overflowing

Comment: You probably want to just return 0 for a null date instead

Comment: if possible i want to return time 7:00 PM for a null date instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: datediff function resulted in an overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275208/sql-server-datediff-function-resulted-in-an-overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
select empid,
convert(varchar(5), sum(datediff(minute, [intime], isnull([outtime], dateadd(hh, 19, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [intime]), 0))))) / 60) 
+ ':' +
convert(varchar(5),sum(datediff(minute, [intime], isnull([outtime], dateadd(hh, 19, DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [intime]), 0))))) % 60)
as TotalHours
from HR_EMPLOYEES group by empid
```

Some thoughts:

1. Can `intime` ever be null? If so how and why? I am assuming `intime` can never be null
2. I am assuming that if `outtime` is `null` then, the employee is still working, thus the use of `getdate()` But it may also be the case that there was a software bug that caused the `null`.
3. Another strategy to handle `null` in `outtime` could be to make it the midnight of the `intime` day. Then this begs the question, how the next day will be handled.

I think there may be a lot of edge cases here. You will have to be careful.

EDIT: Modified `outtime` to 7 PM of `intime` day if `outtime` is null as per OP's comment. Used  [Best approach to remove time part of datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177449/best-approach-to-remove-time-part-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: yeah you are right, intime will not null ever and outtime could be null, so is there any way that i can fill outtime with constant time assume 7:00 pm in the above query. thanks

Comment: Have made changes to the sql code, see if it works. I have not tested it.

Comment: Hi, thanks, above query is working but for some of the employee, minutes is not displaying in total hours,like (10:22 but only displaying 10: mostly when total hours cross more than 10 hours), could please give an idea how to make it correct.

Comment: What are the `intime` and `outtime` of these employees?

Comment: Odd, my query works perfectly for the data you provided. Check if you have any typo in your query, look in the part after `+ ':' +`. By the way if this answer is helping you, don't forget to upvote so that it helps others.

Comment: 'empid intime outtime totalhours remarks
1 7:38 18:00 10:22 but coming 10:
2 9:16 20:03 10:47 but coming 10:
3 9:35 19:56 10:22 but coming 10:
 19:56 19:57  
 20:01 20:01  
 20:03 20:03  
4 10:01 20:02 10:01 correct'

Answer (score 2):

Is it not easier to just discard the null values (returning datediff in seconds from a datetime of zero is what's probably overflowing your query) and also use 'hh' for `datediff`? Or are you also looking for the number of minutes (do you NEED seconds?? If this is for timesheets etc, seconds don't really matter do they?)

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEEID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN In_Time IS NOT NULL AND Out_Time IS NOT NULL THEN sum(DateDiff(hh, In_Time, Out_Time))
        ELSE 0
    END as TotalHours
FROM HR_EMPLOYEES
```

Edit: ok for hours/minutes just use:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEEID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN In_Time IS NOT NULL AND Out_Time IS NOT NULL THEN sum(DateDiff(mi, In_Time, Out_Time)) / 60.0
        ELSE 0
    END as TotalHours
FROM HR_EMPLOYEES
```

This gives you hours plus a fraction of minutes (so 90 minutes = 1.5 hours)

Edit2: if you want minutes as actual minutes and not a fraction use this:

```
SELECT
    EMPLOYEEID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN In_Time IS NOT NULL AND Out_Time IS NOT NULL THEN 
             sum(DateDiff(hh, In_Time, Out_Time) + -- Total hours
             DateDiff(mi, In_Time, Out_Time) % 60 * .01) -- Total minutes (divided by 100 so that you can add it to the hours)
        ELSE 0
    END as TotalHours
FROM HR_EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: :no. i only need hours and minutes

Comment: Ok edited - use the second query no need for all those sums really

Comment: thanks, but could you please tell me how to get in this format (90 minutes = 1.30 hours)

Comment: Modded with option for hours/minutes instead of hours/fraction of minutes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `0` as your default/fixed point in time, use some other constant date instead, that's closer to the values you're going to be processing - and thus less likely to produce an overflow.

`0` gets implicitly converted to midnight on 01/01/1900. A better constant might be, for instance, 01/01/2000:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEEID, sum(DateDiff(mi,isnull(In_Time,'20000101'),isnull(Out_Time,'20000101'))/60) +
sum(round(DateDiff(mi,isnull(In_Time,'20000101'),isnull(Out_Time,'20000101'))%60,2))/100.0    +
sum(round(DateDiff(ss,isnull(In_Time,'20000101'),isnull(Out_Time,'20000101')),2))/10000.0 as
TotalHours from HR_EMPLOYEES
```

Although the more I look at this, the more I'm unsure that defaulting the date to any value even makes sense.

Comment: Agreed on the 'making sense' bit - it would appear that if they don't have an in/out time then the hours worked can't be calculated (I worked 17 thousand hours this week boss ;))

Comment: @Damien : thanks, error has gone now, but TotaHours is not calculating correctly for some employee, like 15:36 to 16:37, total hours is coming 1:37, could you please tell where i am doing wrong