# DATEDIFF function resulted in an overflow in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table in SQL Server 2016 with the following data:

```
id     | t                       | memory
-------+-------------------------+------------
620255 | 2017-07-17 16:11:25.100 | 11632640
620127 | 2017-07-17 16:11:24.100 | 11632640
619999 | 2017-07-17 16:11:23.097 | 11632640
619872 | 2017-07-17 16:11:22.097 | 11632640
```

I am trying to get the average of the `memory` per second. So in order to do that I tried the below query:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(memory) AS avgMemory, 
    DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, 0, t), 0) AS t 
FROM 
    Table1 AS Table1 
WHERE 
    t BETWEEN '2017-07-17 16:11:00.000' AND '2017-07-17 16:12:00.000' 
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, 0, t), 0) 
ORDER BY 
    t ASC;
```

But upon execution, I get the following error:

> The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

As per the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26730173/sql-server-datediff-function-resulted-in-an-overflow-when-using-millisecond), the maximum difference for seconds can be 68 years, but in my case it is just 60 seconds.

So why am I getting this error? And what can I do to resolve it?

Here is the SQLFiddle with the mentioned issue: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd8af/1)

Comment: To me, it looks like you're computing the difference between the date 0 and your t values. Did you want to compute the difference between the minimum t value and the current t value instead?

Comment: There is a problem with `DATEDIFF(second, 0, t)`. What do you want to achive with this?

Comment: I am trying to group the timestamp on seconds/minutes/hours (depends on the user selection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the "starting date".

In `select  DATEDIFF(second, 0, t)`  0 means 1900-01-01 that is too distant from 2017, so the time in seconds passed from 1900-01-01 to 2017-07-17 overflows simple integer, it's not just "60 seconds"

Comment: Yes, thank you for the idea. I updated my starting date from 0 to 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 as I know I don't have a timestamp before that in my table.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server offers `datediff_big()` for this purpose:

```
SELECT AVG(memory) AS avgMemory,
       DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF_BIG(second, 0, t), 0) AS t 
FROM Table1 AS Table1 
WHERE t BETWEEN '2017-07-17 16:11:00.000' AND '2017-07-17 16:12:00.000' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF_BIG(second, 0, t), 0) 
ORDER BY t ASC;
```

You could also do this by converting the value to a string:

```
SELECT AVG(memory) AS avgMemory,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), t, 120) as t
FROM Table1 AS Table1 
WHERE t BETWEEN '2017-07-17 16:11:00.000' AND '2017-07-17 16:12:00.000' 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), t, 120)
ORDER BY t ASC;
```

This version works in all supported versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Starting with 2016, right? And if he is on the previous version?

Comment: @sepupic The OP explicitly mentioned SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I'll try with this.

Comment: @Frank Schmitt When I wrote my comment there was no "2016", only "sql" and "sql server"

Comment: @sepupic The question *body* was edited 44 minutes ago by the OP to include 2016 (your comment was added 39 minutes ago at the time I'm writing this) whereas the 2016 *tag* was indeed added by Gordon Linoff after your comment.

Comment: @ Frank Schmitt really? Even now when I read your post, my comment has 43 minutes and post edits has 43 minutes

Comment: The `DATEDIFF_BIG` can return difference of max 68 years for second. As I am subtracting from 0 (1900-01-01), it will still overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a different date (e.g. `2017-07-17 00:00:00.000`) as the fixpoint for your calculations:

```
SELECT AVG(memory) AS memory, 
  DATEADD(second, 
          DATEDIFF(second, '2017-07-17 00:00:00.000', t),
          '2017-07-17 00:00:00.000') AS t 
FROM Table1 AS Table1 
WHERE t BETWEEN '2017-07-17 16:11:00.000' AND '2017-07-17 16:12:00.000' 
GROUP BY DATEADD(second, 
                 DATEDIFF(second, '2017-07-17 00:00:00.000', t), 
                 '2017-07-17 00:00:00.000') 
ORDER BY t ASC;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd8af/9)

Comment: The start and end dates come from the UI, so I cannot have a static date.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your answer, but now I get what you are talking about. And it works. I changed the starting date to 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 0):

pre 2016 db, on a group by, i had to cast the datediff as bigint then get the avg, for datediff by ms.
avg(cast(datediff(ms,sdate,edate)) as BIGINT)) as theavg