# Get time in HH:MM:SS.nnn format?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the time in the format of `HH:MM:SS.nnn` using the SQL `convert()` function

I currently using this to get the time difference in `HH:MM:SS` format

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime), 0), 0),108)
```

But now I want the time format to show milliseconds in the form of `HH:MM:SS.nnn` with the (.) as a separator not the (:) as how the format code 114 can do.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like you want format 126, ISO 8601 with time.

Comment: Have you tried the `FORMAT` function?

Comment: BTW - that format would normally be expressed as `HH:mm:ss.mmm` if you want 24 hour time and `hh:mm:ss.mmm` if not

Comment: Consider:

`SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(15),GETUTCDATE(),114)`

Answer (score 0):

Using datediff in milliseconds can overflow easily, so be cautious of relying on that. (Max. duration is is [24 days, 20 hours, 31 minutes and 23.647 seconds.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26730333/2067753))

Style **108** produces HH:MM:SS , whereas style **114** supplies  HH:MM:SS.nnn , or you can use `FORMAT(..., 'hh:mm:ss.fff')` e.g:

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), 
   DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime), 0), 0)
     ,114)
```

However `DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime)` could be greater than 24 hours, if that is the case no "time only" style is going to display hours larger than 23. So if you need to cater for more than 24 hours you will need to calculate your own hh:mm:ss.nnn string - example below

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  IssueDatetime DATETIME,
  CalledDateTime DATETIME
);


INSERT INTO t (IssueDatetime, CalledDateTime)
VALUES ('2023-05-30 10:30:00.002', '2023-06-01 14:53:42.346');
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
select
     by_style114 = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12), 
          DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime), 0), 0) 
         ,114) 
  , by_format = FORMAT(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime), 0), 0), 'hh:mm:ss.fff')
  , by_concat = concat(DATEDIFF(hour, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime) 
               , ':' , DATEDIFF(minute, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime) % 60 
               , ':' , DATEDIFF(second, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime) % 60 
               , '.' , DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, T.IssueDatetime, T.CalledDateTime) % 188622000 )
from t
```

| by_style114 | by_format | by_concat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 04:23:42:343 | 04:23:42.343 | 52:23:42.343 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Qvw_9mQy)

Comment: Using `VARCHAR` without a length is a [bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), even if it happens to work in this case because it's defaulting to `VARCHAR(30)`. Repeated conversion and concatenation is more succinctly done with `CONCAT`, as it takes care of the conversion on its own.

Comment: I keep forgetting that concat() has more than 2 parameters in TSQL now, so yes - that would be much more succinct.