# Overflow Error in Access 2013 Updating Table

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to update a linked table in Access 2013. The Table DP is a MySql table which I am using ODBC to access. The Table ND is a local table in the Access database (MDB format). I am doing plenty of other update queries to DP so the actual technique is not an issue. The text field I am updating has a length of 50 but I am checking that in case that is the source of the Overflow. The other field I am updating is just an Integer.

```
UPDATE DP INNER JOIN ND ON (DP.DOD = ND.DOD) AND (DP.DOB = ND.DOB) AND (DP.Name = ND.Name) 
SET DP.CategoryId = 1, DP.Description = [ND].[Description]
WHERE (((DP.Description)="XYZ") AND ((ND.Description)<>"XYZ") 
AND ((Len([ND].[Description]))<=50));
```

When I run the query Access just says "Overflow".

What in this query could possibly be causing an overflow?

I should add that DOB and DOD are date fields and some of my dates go back to the first century AD.

Comment: What are the properties of the Description field on both tables?

Comment: ND - Long Text, 

DP - Short Text, field size 50 (that's what Access shows in the attached table)
DP - VARCHAR(50) in MySql

Comment: While the error seems fairly straight forward, trying to fit something large into something smaller.  I haven't ran into this situation myself, though to I think to possibly explain this what happens if you run a query that gets the length of all records from ND that will be getting updated into DP and see if any exceed 50.

Comment: Also from my understanding longtext automatically holds enough characters for 65000 characters and I haven't seen it explicitly limit to 50.  For reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ce25934-beb4-4468-9cdd-16419ddd3438/a2013-short-text-long-text-rich-text-differences-and-why-you-can-only-see-rich-text-as-choice?forum=accessdev

Comment: Actually I just noticed that the scroll bar perfectly cuts off the <= 50 part of your query on my screen.

Comment: I have a feeling it might be down to the dates that I am using in the join. Access doesn't have the date range that MySql has and early dates might be causing the problem. I shall investigate.

Comment: You could be right, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275208/sql-server-datediff-function-resulted-in-an-overflow is worth a read.  Seems like in the comparison of dates SQL does an internal datediff and if there are any dates that differ greater than 68 years you get that error.