# SQL Server - DateTime comparison OverFlows INT value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a process that compares two DateTime values together to make sure that Activity occurs after Received time. Because we allow 60 seconds of leeway, I previously had a delete statement with the following where clause.

```
i.ActivityDateTime < i.ReceivedDateTime 
  AND
DATEDIFF(ss, i.ActivityDateTime, i.ReceivedDateTime) > 60
```

This process ran fine for a long time until we received a time many, many years in the past. Since DateDiff returns an integer, the comparison overflowed the value and the process failed.

A fix I have in place now is

```
i.ActivityDateTime < i.ReceivedDateTime 
  AND
(
  DATEDIFF(yy, i.ActivityDateTime, i.ReceivedDateTime) > 0
   OR 
  DATEDIFF(ss, i.ActivityDateTime, i.ReceivedDateTime) > 60
)
```

Testing has gone well with this process so far, but my worry is that I am missing something and, in the future, I may have another failure based on some other combination of Activity and Received time.

Has anyone else experienced something similar, and what other possible comparisons can I perform so that I can make sure no issues happen in the future?

Comment: Probably not going to help you at all right now, but in SQL Server 2016 onwards, there's a new function called DATEDIFF_BIG.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt628058.aspx

Comment: Does the first answer here help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275208/sql-server-datediff-function-resulted-in-an-overflow

Comment: since you are checking for greather than 1 min, why use DATEDIFF ( MINUTE, date1, date2) > 1 ?

Comment: @mcr - Thanks, I did not know about the DateDiff_Big function. I think there is a mistake in the Return Value portion of the text where it gives the same amount for "maximum return values" as the regular DateDiff function.

Comment: @Squirrel - I think we want to keep the seconds comparison for now, changing to minute definitely bumps the maximum time up (60x higher to be exact) between the two dates. I believe, after testing, that the Year comparison pulls out all datetimes that would overflow either minute or second before the other comparison occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using DATEDIFF you could take a different route entirely. Consider the following example.

```
DECLARE @ActivityDateTime DATETIME, @ReceivedDateTime DATETIME

-- The info was received on this date.
SET @ReceivedDateTime = GETDATE()

-- Let's pretend that the activity ocurred on this date.
-- Adjust the number of seconds to pretend a different date. :)
SET @ActivityDateTime = DATEADD(SECOND, 29, @ReceivedDateTime)

-- If you add 30 seconds to the receive date and it's larger than the
-- receive date then it means that the activity occurred less than
-- 30 seconds after the received date.
IF DATEADD(SECOND, 30, @ReceivedDateTime) > @ActivityDateTime BEGIN
    PRINT 'The activity ocurred more than 30 seconds after the receive date...'
END
```

I'm not entirely sure that my example meets your exact needs but if not it should be easy to tweak.

Good luck!